# JavaScript adding to a variable and displaying result in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm just learning the basics of javaScript and jquery and have tried to put together this simple program http://codepen.io/mike-grifin/pen/oXjVYW. It's simply a box that displays a number and there is two buttons, one adds 10 and the other button subtracts 10. Ive set the output to alert and it seems to be working fine but if I remove the alert (below) it's not inputting the results into the container div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var startPoint = +90;
  $(document).find('#container').append(startPoint);

    if($('.increase').click(function(){
      startPoint += +10;

    }));
```

I've also tried to append the startPoint var again but it doesn't overwrite the original:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var startPoint = +90;

$(document).find('#container').append(startPoint);

    if($('.increase').click(function(){
      startPoint += +10;

      $(document).find('#container').append(startPoint);

    }));
```

All the code is at the codepen link. I'm just learning so sorry if it's really obvious or easy. Any educational input or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: change ".append" to ".html" -> $(document).find('#container').html(startPoint);

Comment: Try using `$(document).find('#container').html(startPoint);` to replace the html inside #container and set the new value.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/urLr82eL/ check this

Comment: Do you mean if you want to increase or decrease result should be display in container right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're *appending* the value to the `#container` element. If you want to directly alter the text, you can use jQuery's `text()` method:

```
$(document).find('#container').text(startPoint);
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqGJaJ)

This will overwrite the current text with the new text you're passing in.

> #### `.text(text)`
>
> Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.
>
> – [jQuery's `text()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

---

It's worth also noting that your `if (startPoint >= 100)` check will only be executed when your CodePen demo first loads. If you want to use this check, you'd need to place the `if` statement within your `click` event handlers.

Comment: Brilliant!! I have to wait 6 minutes to mark your answer as correct but i'll do so! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to either set the `.text()` of the `#container` to the new value, or `.empty()` the old data out of it before you `.append()` any more.

```
$('.increase').click(function(){
  $('#container').text(startPoint += +10);
});
```

Also, you don't need to wrap the `$('.increase').click()` in an `if`
It will fire when it is clicked, you don't need to say "`if` (this is clicked)"

It is implied by the `.click()` function

Comment: No problem, ironmike. If you are still learning javascript you might want to have a look at this website, it's very good. http://www.codecademy.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the contents before appending

i used empty()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var startPoint = 90;
      $('#container').empty().append(startPoint);

        if($('.increase').click(function(){
          startPoint += 10;
          $('#container').empty().append(startPoint);
        }));

        if($('.decrease').click(function(){
          startPoint -= 10;
          $('#container').empty().append(startPoint);
        }));

        if(startPoint >= +100){
           $('#container').empty().append(startPoint);
        }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all .. for div you can use .text()  or .html()
2nd .. move your if statement into .increase click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var startPoint = +90;
       $(document).find('#container').append(startPoint);
        $('.increase').on('click',function(){
           if(startPoint >= +100){
              alert('dayum!!');
           }else{
              $('#container').text(startPoint += +10);
           }
        });
        $('.decrease').on('click',function(){
          $('#container').text(startPoint -= +10);
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp And
[.html() and .append() without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136012/html-and-append-without-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var startPoint = +90;
      $(document).find('#container').append(startPoint);

        if($('.increase').click(function(){
          alert(startPoint += +10);
          $("#container").html(startPoint) //added
        }));

        if($('.decrease').click(function(){
          alert(startPoint -= +10);
          $("#container").html(startPoint) //added
        }));

        if(startPoint >= +100){
          alert('dayum!!');
        }

  });
```

use this code, this helps you :)